# whenever i run a program in VS code a notification pop-up from windows security and vs code takes some time to run the code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

whenever i run the code in VS code i got a notification from windows security which goes like :

**windows security**

**virus and threat protection**

**security scan required**

your administrator requires a scan of this item. this scan could take upto 10 seconds

*and code doesn't run until i close this notification. i tried to solve this problem by disabling-enabling the code runner extension but i still get the notification pls help me to solve this problem.*